# ReactorClientHttpConnector((<no type> opt) -> {}) is undefined

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, netty, spring-webflow

I need help for WebFlux client implementation for the latest version spring-webflux 5.1.3.RELEASE.

```
public RestClient(String gatewayUrl, String token, String username, String password, SslContext sslContext) {
        this.token = token;
        WebClient.Builder builder = WebClient.builder().baseUrl(gatewayUrl);
        if (sslContext != null) {
            ClientHttpConnector httpConnector = new ReactorClientHttpConnector(opt -> opt.sslContext(sslContext));
            builder.clientConnector(httpConnector);
        }
        if (username != null && password != null) {
            builder.filter(basicAuthentication(username, password));
        }
        client = builder.build();
    }

    public Mono<Response> execute(Transaction transaction) {
        Mono<Transaction> transactionMono = Mono.just(transaction);
        return client.post().uri("/v1/{token}", token)
                .header(HttpHeaders.USER_AGENT, "client")
                .accept(MediaType.APPLICATION_XML)
                .contentType(MediaType.APPLICATION_XML)
                .body(transactionMono, Transaction.class)
                .retrieve()
                .bodyToMono(Response.class);
    }
```

I get error `The constructor ReactorClientHttpConnector((<no type> opt) -> {}) is undefined` at this line `ClientHttpConnector httpConnector = new ReactorClientHttpConnector(opt -> opt.sslContext(sslContext));`

Do you know how I can fix this issue?

Comment: What is the parameter type of the `ReactorClientHttpConnecter` constructor?

Comment: https://docs.spring.io/spring-framework/docs/current/javadoc-api/org/springframework/http/client/reactive/ReactorClientHttpConnector.html

Comment: From that documentation that you linked, that constructor accepts a `reactor.netty.http.client.HttpClient`. The documentation for that class shows that it is not a functional interface, so you cannot use a lambda there.

Comment: I see. Any idea what will be the solution work with ssl context?

Comment: I’ve never really worked with these frameworks, but you’ll need to pass in an `HttpClient` instance where you specifically set the `sslContext`.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

From the [doc](https://docs.spring.io/spring/docs/5.1.4.RELEASE/spring-framework-reference/web-reactive.html#webflux-client-builder-reactor), you need to provide a pre-defined  `reactor.netty.http.client.HttpClient` to construct the `ReactorClientHttpConnector`.

For example:

```
HttpClient httpClient = HttpClient.create().secure(sslContextSpec -> sslContextSpec.sslContext(sslContext));
ClientHttpConnector httpConnector = new ReactorClientHttpConnector(httpClient);
```